# Null variable FormValidation error Symfony Form builder

Tags: php, symfony

I can't pass a null value through the validation of my form, this is my code (I'll only show you the necessary part of the code) :

Form :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder
        ->add('text', TextType::class , array(
            'required' => false,
            'empty_data' => null,
        ))
}
```

My entity (it's a Trait) :

```
trait TextTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $text = null;

    /**
     * Set text
     *
     * @param string $text
     */
    public function setText(?string $text = null)
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText() : ?string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
```

The error :

[image]

How can i pass a null variable in a symfony form ??

Comment: `empty_data` is set to null by default.

Comment: ok, but i tried so much parameters with so much values, don't know what to do anymore, is it a bug ?

Comment: did you use the trait in the entity class itself?

Comment: `The default value is '' (the empty string)` I think if you realy want the type `NULL` you have to write a `DataTransformer` for this.

Comment: Yes I used the Trait in my entity Class

Comment: I set the 'empty_data' to "", now i only have the error, "This value should not be empty" ...

Comment: Have you validated that this value can be empty? I mean removed `Assert\NotBlank` for e.g and updated the schema to be nullable?

Comment: With the code above, the value IS `null`. But you somewhere have defined validation constraints which declare that your property must not be `null`. You need to adapt these constraints too.